# saveToFile not showing images into gallery

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-camera

I created a nativescript app for camara related app. I am taking a photo using nativescript-camara module.

once user take a photo I am showing that image preview, as well as user can rename that image name. When user save that image I stored into a specific folder and removing preview image which stored by nativescript-camara module.

after that, i can see that image in the gallery but not the original image, I can only blank image in the gallery. I also checked that image is exist on that location where is saved it. That means, Image saving work perfects but not showing that image in the gallery immediately. After 5-10 minutes i can see that image in gallery. But not an immediately.

here is more details with images
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/issues/222

Comment: Try [enabling trace module](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/trace) and check if you see the [scan completed log](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/blob/master/src/camera.android.ts#L100). If you don't until that 5-10 minutes, that could mean Android is still working on getting a preview image. What device you used to test? Did you try a different device / OS version?

Comment: There are a diffrent behaviours on the devices:
- At one tablet nothing is found in gallery (doesn't matter if deleting cache, restart and more...)
- At one phone it's working good more or less, only a little time gap. But the original image is still existing.
- At one phone it's displaying "broken images", randomly sometimes after restart or emptying cache it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! i solved this issue, I scanned media and its done. Here is my code.

```
var callback = new android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener({
      onScanCompleted: function (path, uri) {
          console.log(path)
        }
    });

    android.media.MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(applicationModule.android.context, [path], null, callback);
```